# Count array numbers in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array named

```
$results['picks]
```

the vardump of array is:

```
var_dump($results['picks']

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "55"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "69"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "71"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "72"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "73"
}
```

How to count all arrays inside?
results are 5 so i need to get that number
i was trying with

```
count();
```

but i get this result:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: I think $results['picks'] is containing 5 different arrays. That's why count() giving five 1's. so , if You want the result as 5 then first merge all of those arrays then use count()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for this-
You need to count the array value recursively as it is multidimensional array

```
<?php
$food = array('fruits' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple'),
              'veggie' => array('carrot', 'collard', 'pea'));

// recursive count
echo count($food, COUNT_RECURSIVE); // output 8

// normal count
echo count($food); // output 2

?>
```

You can get more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

You are still having problem, so i created PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uzs-qvy

Please take a look at that.

Comment: both echos return me
    1 1 1 1 1

Answer (score 0):

you are getting 1s in you code from first post, because instead of trying to access the values you already have in you array (that in my understanding represent the "count" you need to fetch) - you count the number of elements in that array.

If I understand well what are you trying to accomplish - you can do it with the below code.

```
//if you want to get just the 5 numbers (written are shown as strings in your var dump), which as I undersand you store your count values

$extracted_arr = array_map(function($item){ return array_shift($item); }, $result['picks']); 

foreach($extracted_arr as $count)
    echo $count; 

// you should see 55 69 71 72 73
```

**EDIT: including your comments**

```
//this should get you what you need

//create an array of counts
$count_arr = array_map(function($item){ return count($item); }, $result['picks']); 

//sum these counts
$five = array_sum($count_arr);
```

Comment: I want to count the number of arrays in
55 are 1, 69 are another 1 ... all of them is = 5
i need that "5" number only :-)

Comment: The result again is 
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: There is no echo in the second code fragment so you might be doing something wrong or using the first code snippet. If you run the second one you should get "5" if you echo $five;

Comment: put the whole code you are using into your question, I suspect you are trying to use my code inside a foreach loop, and it's wrong. In my soulution you arent supposed to "count" each element of the $result['picks'] separately - the data is aggregated by the array_sum function into a single number (which of course is a sum). Instead of doing a foreach, and getting 1 1 1 1 1 you array_sum the arrray you'd feed into the foreach and get 5.

Comment: I'm Sorry it's my bad.
I echo this in a while()
because there i set this parameters to $results['picks']
Its in a multy-query and i have troubles to get this into a variable array outside the loop